# How to control the flow of requests in scrapy when handling Google recaptcha v2 with deathbycaptcha service?

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, scrapy, recaptcha

Hello :)  I am working with the scrapy web crawling framework using python, scraping a website and solving the captcha that I encounter on their page with the deathbycaptcha service.  My download delay is set to 30 seconds and I am only scraping a few pages to get basic information that way I don't intrude on the sites bandwidth too much or anything of the sorts.  I treat scraping like an experience that would occur on a regular browser.

So firstly let's talk about the issues.

*ISSUE 1* (in code)
How do I get scrapy to basically stop creating new requests, or messing with the captcha too much while it is being solved?  I have tried a lot of different things all have come to no avail, and I am fairly new to scrapy so I am not well versed in editing the downloader middlewares or scrapy engine code but if that's the only way to do it then so be it but I am hoping for a very simple and efficient solution to just let the captcha do it's thing, without the new requests interrupting it at all.

*ISSUE 2* (in code)
How do I fix this timer function which I think kinda correlates with the first issue.  If the timeout on the captcha goes out without solving then it will never reset the `captchaIsRunning` boolean and continually disallows the captcha to start trying to solve again.  The timer is there as one of my attempted solutions to the first issue but...  I get an error for it.  Not sure if it has anything to do with the fact that is is pulled from `threading` and `timeit` in the import statements but I didn't think it made a big difference.  Can anyone guide me in the right direction for fixing the Timer statement?

Like I said the deathbycaptcha API runs fine, when it has the chance to but the scrapy requests are really interfering and I haven't been able to find a relevant solution to this problem.  Again I am not a scrapy expert yet so some things have been far out of my comfort zone, which needs to be pushed, but not too hard that I end up breaking everything xD  Thank you for the help it is greatly appreciated!  Sorry for this super long question.

Anyway, the page lets you look up a couple results and after about oh say 40-60 pages it redirects to a captcha page which has recaptcha v2.  The deathbycaptcha service has an API for solving the recaptcha v2 but unfortunately their solving time can be well over a couple minutes sometimes which is very disappointing but it happens.  So naturally I adjusted my `DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT` setting to `240` seconds so that it had plenty of time to solve the captcha, and continue scraping after that so that it didn't redirect anymore.  My scrapy settings are as follows:

```
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1
DEPTH_LIMIT = 1
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 30
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 1
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 1
DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 240
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 10
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
```

And then obviously the rest but I figured that these were the most important ones for my issue.  I have one extension enabled and then the middlewares have a couple extra things in it because I was also working with docker and scrapy-splash in this file.

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}

MYEXT_ENABLED = False
MYEXT_ITEMCOUNT = 100

EXTENSIONS = {
   'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
   'scrapy.extensions.spideroclog.SpiderOpenCloseLogging':500,
}
```

So I don't think that this stuff affects the captcha or downloader middlewares a whole lot...  But here is some of the code from my scraper:

**Python:**

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(r'F:\Documents\ScrapyDirectory\scrapername\scrapername\spiders')
import deathbycaptcha
import json
import scrapy
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import math
import urllib
import time
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from threading import Timer
from timeit import Timer

class scrapername(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "scrapername"
    start_urls = []

    global scrapeUrlList
    global charCompStorage
    global captchaIsRunning

    r = requests.get('http://example.com/examplejsonfeed.php')

    myObject = json.loads(r.text)

    #print("Loading names...")
    for o in myObject['objects']:
        #a huge function for creating basically a lot of objects and appending links created from these objects to the scrapeUrlList function

    print(len(scrapeUrlList))
    for url in scrapeUrlList:
        start_urls.append(url[1])
        #add all those urls that just got created to the start_urls list


    link_collection = []

    def resetCaptchaInformation():
        global captchaIsRunning
        if captchaIsRunning:
            captchaIsRunning = False

    def afterCaptchaSubmit(self, response):
        global captchaIsRunning
        print("Captcha submitted: " + response.request.url)
        captchaIsRunning = False

    def parse(self, response):
        global captchaIsRunning
        self.logger.info("got response %s for %r" % (response.status, response.url))

        if "InternalCaptcha" in response.request.url:
        #checks for captcha in the url and if it's there it starts running the captcha solver API
            if not captchaIsRunning:
            #I have this statement here as a deterrent to prevent the captcha solver from starting again and again and 
            #again with every new request (which it does)  *ISSUE 1*
                if "captchasubmit" in response.request.url:
                    print("Found captcha submit in url")
                else:
                    print("Internal Captcha is activated")
                    captchaIsRunning = True
                    t = Timer(240.0, self.resetCaptchaInformation)
                    #so I have been having major issues here not sure why?
                    #*ISSUE 2*
                    t.start()

                    username = "username"
                    password = "password"

                    print("Set username and password")

                    Captcha_dict = {
                    'googlekey': '6LcMUhgUAAAAAPn2MfvqN9KYxj7KVut-oCG2oCoK',
                    'pageurl': response.request.url}

                    print("Created catpcha dict")

                    json_Captcha = json.dumps(Captcha_dict)

                    print("json.dumps on captcha dict:")
                    print(json_Captcha)

                    client = deathbycaptcha.SocketClient(username, password)

                    print("Set up client with deathbycaptcha socket client")

                    try:
                        print("Trying to solve captcha")
                        balance = client.get_balance()

                        print("Remaining Balance: " + str(balance))

                        # Put your CAPTCHA type and Json payload here:
                        captcha = client.decode(type=4,token_params=json_Captcha)

                        if captcha:
                            # The CAPTCHA was solved; captcha["captcha"] item holds its
                            # numeric ID, and captcha["text"] item its a text token".
                            print("CAPTCHA %s solved: %s" % (captcha["captcha"], captcha["text"]))

                            data = {
                                'g-recaptcha-response':captcha["text"],
                            }

                            try:
                                dest = response.xpath("/html/body/form/@action").extract_first()
                                print("Form URL: " + dest)
                                submitURL = "https://exampleaddress.com" + dest
                                yield scrapy.FormRequest(url=submitURL, formdata=data, callback=self.afterCaptchaSubmit, dont_filter = True)

                                print("Yielded form request")

                                if '':  # check if the CAPTCHA was incorrectly solved
                                    client.report(captcha["captcha"])
                            except TypeError:
                                sys.exit()
                    except deathbycaptcha.AccessDeniedException:
                        # Access to DBC API denied, check your credentials and/or balance
                        print("error: Access to DBC API denied, check your credentials and/or balance")
            else:
                pass
        else:
            print("no Captcha")
            #this will run if no captcha is on the page that the redirect landed on
            #and basically parses all the information on the page
```

So sorry for all that code, thank you for your patience in reading through it.  If you have any questions as to why something is there just ask so I can explain.  SO the captcha DOES solve.  That is not the issue.  When the scraper is running and there is many requests happening and it runs into a 302 redirect it then gets a 200 response and crawls the page, detects the captcha and starts solving it.  Then scrapy sends another request, which gets 302 redirect, 200 response on the captcha page and detects the captcha and tries to solve it again.  It was starting the API multiple times and wasting my tokens.  Hence the `if not captchaIsRunning:` statements being there to stop that from happening.  So here is the scrapy logs that i have right now being outputted when it hits the captcha, bear in mind everything before this was just fine, running all my parsing logs.

**Scrapy Logs:**

```
2018-07-19 14:10:35 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.exampleaddress.com/InternalCaptcha?returnUrl=%2fresults%3fname%3dThomas%2520Garrett%26citystatezip%3dLas%2520Vegas%2c%2520Nv> from <GET https://www.exampleaddress.com/results?name=Thomas%20Garrett&citystatezip=Las%20Vegas,%20Nv>
2018-07-19 14:10:49 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.exampleaddress.com/InternalCaptcha?returnUrl=%2fresults%3fname%3dThomas%2520Garrett%26citystatezip%3dLas%2520Vegas%2c%2520Nv> (referer: None)
2018-07-19 14:10:49 [scrapername] INFO: got response 200 for 'https://www.exampleaddress.com/InternalCaptcha?returnUrl=%2fresults%3fname%3dThomas%2520Garrett%26citystatezip%3dLas%2520Vegas%2c%2520Nv'
Internal Captcha is activated
2018-07-19 14:10:49 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.exampleaddress.com/InternalCaptcha?returnUrl=%2fresults%3fname%3dThomas%2520Garrett%26citystatezip%3dLas%2520Vegas%2c%2520Nv> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy_splash\middleware.py", line 156, in process_spider_output
    for el in result:
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "F:\Documents\ScrapyDirectory\scraperName\scraperName\spiders\scraperName- Copy.py", line 232, in parse
    t = Timer(240.0, self.resetCaptchaInformation)
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\timeit.py", line 130, in __init__
    raise ValueError("stmt is neither a string nor callable")
ValueError: stmt is neither a string nor callable
2018-07-19 14:10:53 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 63 pages (at 2 pages/min), scraped 13 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-07-19 14:11:02 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.exampleaddress.com/InternalCaptcha?returnUrl=%2fresults%3fname%3dSamuel%2520Van%2520Cleave%26citystatezip%3dLas%2520Vegas%2c%2520Nv> from <GET https://www.exampleaddress.com/results?name=Samuel%20Van%20Cleave&citystatezip=Las%20Vegas,%20Nv>
2018-07-19 14:11:13 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.exampleaddress.com/InternalCaptcha?returnUrl=%2fresults%3fname%3dSamuel%2520Van%2520Cleave%26citystatezip%3dLas%2520Vegas%2c%2520Nv> (referer: None)
2018-07-19 14:11:13 [scrapername] INFO: got response 200 for 'https://www.exampleaddress.com/InternalCaptcha?returnUrl=%2fresults%3fname%3dSamuel%2520Van%2520Cleave%26citystatezip%3dLas%2520Vegas%2c%2520Nv'
#and then an endless supply of 302 redirects, and 200 response for their crawl
#nothing happens, because the Timer failed, the captcha never solved?
#I'm not sure what is going wrong with it, hence the issues I am having
```

Comment: related project [decaptcha](https://github.com/yetone/decaptcha): Scrapy middleware, reCAPTCHA, deathbycaptcha

Answer (score 0):

I still need some weeks of more experience to solve your problem, but I would try using the RetryMiddleware:

Probably adding 302 to the retry codes is enough:

```
RETRY_HTTP_CODES
Default: [500, 502, 503, 504, 408]
```

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#retry-http-codes

Comment: That's a valid suggestion thank you :)  Unfortunately I don't think that it will solve my problem, seeing as I don't need the 302 to be retried.  The 302 runs just fine, redirects me to the captcha page and then gives me a 200 response for that page, in which my captcha solving code begins to execute :)  All totally fine.  So I am assuming your solution might be targeted towards my Timer function maybe?  Either way I need it to retry in 4 minutes or whatever time I set, if it hasn't finished solving yet.   I really just need the 302 to run once, until the captcha is done.

Comment: Once the captcha is solved there won't be anymore 302 redirects until the website decides it wants to put another captcha up for me.  Once the captcha is solved it crawls 200's all day.  The issue lies in the fact that if I don't solve the captcha is will keep sending 302 logs as you can see in the Scrapy Logs section of my code.