# Solving reCAPTCHA with scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, recaptcha

I am using scrapy to crawl some webpages. But at some point, Google reCAPTCHA blocks the way.

Google reCAPTCHA even doesn't load if the browser(scrapy in this case) doesn't have a running javascript. It simply asks you to enable your javascript to view and solve the reCAPTCHA.

So, I think that, if I can find a way to show this reCAPTCHA to user when it occurs, user can manually solve this and scrapy continues to crawl but I couldn't a way to interrupt this process with a real javascript. What can I use at this point ? Is it possible to mix selenium with scrapy ?

Comment: A reCATCHA is the ultimate way a website can notify you that it does not want to be scrapped.

Comment: @akshaypatil  Any reason to mark the normal texts as _Code Samples_? I have reverted back the changes. Moving forward please take care.

Comment: instead of focusing on that we expect you to answer..@DebanjanB

Comment: https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash
I found this library. I didn't try it yet but it can be useful.

Comment: You could try something like [rapidapi.com/acrogenesis-llc-api/api/recaptcha-solver1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55018702/solving-recaptcha-with-scrapy)

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you want to build something *semi*-automatic. Scrapy is not good for that, and as you say, it cannot handle javascript.

I would recommend trying selenium. It launches a full chrome browser and is scriptable. See https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

You can stop the script and some event (e.g. reCAPTCHA) and then let the user take over.

Comment: It wouldn't be useful in my case. Yes, you are right. I want something semi-automatic but this service will run for clients over a website for example. Selenium will make things much much slower, even I make a connection with client web server and selenium. So, I have to use something like scrapy.

Comment: ideally the browser (selenium/puppeteer/playwright/...) is only used when a captcha was found, similar to jdownloader captcha popups. and/or use a captcha solver like deathbycaptcha. but i have not-yet found a implementation for this. related: [How to control the flow of requests in scrapy when handling Google recaptcha v2 with deathbycaptcha service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51434467/how-to-control-the-flow-of-requests-in-scrapy-when-handling-google-recaptcha-v2)